# rdd.histogram gives "can not generate buckets with non-number in RDD" error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Use the following one-column dataframe,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
df.show()

+---+
| _1|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
+---+
```

The compute a histogram using rdd's histogram function.

```
df.rdd.histogram(2)
```

Then I get an error: Can not generate buckets with non-number in RDD. I am confused because all values in my dataframe are numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `df.rdd` is a RDD of rows, and rows are not numbers. You can verify it by calling collect in the pyspark shell for instance:

```py
>>> df.rdd.collect()
[Row(_1=1), Row(_1=2), Row(_1=3), Row(_1=4), Row(_1=5)]
```

To make this work, you can simply extract your numeric column from the row like this:

```py
>>> df.rdd.map(lambda x : x[0]).histogram(2)
([1, 3, 5], [2, 3])
```